# NGRX8 reducer error message: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ListItem[]'

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-reducers

I am trying to set up NGRX to update an array of list items.

This is my reducer:

```
export const initialState: Array<ListItem> = [
  {name: 'list item', quantity: 1}
  ];

// tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
const _listReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(add, (state, {name, quantity}) => (state.push({name: name, quantity: quantity})))
);

export function listReducer(state: ListItem[] | undefined, action: Action) {
  return _listReducer(state, action);
}
```

And the associated action

```
export const add = createAction(
  '[List Component] Add',
  props<{name: string; quantity: number}>()
  );
```

My question is how to I properly push a new entry into the state array from the reducer? currenlly I am getting this error

```
ERROR in src/app/reducers/list.reducer.ts(12,40): error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ListItem[]'.
```

Answer (score 0):

the 'on' statement should have looked like this

```
  on(add, (state, {name, quantity}) => ([...state, {name, quantity}]))
```